# How do I get the "You have 2 attempts left!" alert to reflect the number of login attempts decrementing?

Tags: javascript, html

Html document containing a form that is validated by an external JS function

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
    <head>
        <meta charset = "utf-8">
        <!--CSS-->
        <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "Random.css">
        <!--External JS-->
        <script src = "Random.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--Form containing 2 label elements and 3 input elements-->
        <form id = "myForm" action = "Random.html" method = "POST">
            <label id = "usernameLabel">Username:</label>
            <input id = "username" type = "text" required>
            <br>
            <label id = "passwordLabel">Password:</label>
            <input id = "password" type = "password" maxlength = "12" required>
            <be>
            <!--When submit button is clicked, function called "validate" is called-->
            <input id = "submit" type = "submit" value = "Submit" onclick = "validate()">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Javascript code

Function called "validate" which will validate an HTML form when a submit button is clicked

```js
var login_Attempts = 3; //Global variable

function validate() {
    var username = document.getElementById("username").value; //Local variable
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value; //Local variable
    if (username == "user" && password == "123") {
        alert("Logged in!");
    }
```

If the above if statement is not true, then the max amount of login attempts will decrement by 1

```js
else {
    --login_Attempts;
    errorMessage("You have " + login_Attempts + " attempts left!");
}
```

If login attempts reach 0, then all inputs and submit button will be disabled

```js
if (login_Attempts == 0) {
    username = document.getElementById("username").disabled = true;
    password = document.getElementById("password").disabled = true;
    var submit = document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true; /*Local variable*/
    errorMessage("You've reached the maximum amount of login attempts and will 
        be locked out!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a bit more detail than "it's not working?" What's the behavior you're seeing?

Comment: Please add how do you call the `validate()` function and the HTML Code associated with it

Comment: `login_attempts` needs to be a global variable. Otherwise it resets to `3` every time the function is called.

Comment: Sure thing Nick.  The first time I enter an incorrect username and password, then press the submit button, the alert saying "You have 2 attempts left!" appears, but it keeps saying "2 attempts" when I repeat the same action instead of decrementing to 0 as I want it to.

Comment: This is a common beginner mistake.

Comment: Harshana Serasinghe, I added the associated HTML code just now, as well as a comment above the input element with the ID "submit" explaining how the validate() function is called. I hope it helps.

Comment: Barmar, I just now changed login_attempts to a global variable as you suggested.